# Importing Excel spread sheet with desc, northing and easting into Google Earth to make KMZ

Tags: coordinates, import, utm

I have a spreadsheet with three columns containing a Description, a Northing and an Easting in UTM. Instead of entering the points in by hand, I want to find a faster method.

Comment: Please improve this question, you require latitude and longitude coordinates for Google Earth. Suggest you use fusion tables http://www.geospatialtraining.com/blog/?p=1761

Answer (score 2):

If you have the coordinates in your Excel table, you can import that into QGIS, add a Openlayers Google background for checking if it is right aligned, and save the layer to kml or kmz.